# MySQL database not receiving data from form

Tags: php, mysql

- List item

I am currently trying to insert data to a mysql database from a form but it keeps adding an empty string, if anyone could take a look at my code and let me know if there is an issue it would be greatly appreciated.

the form:

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="input.php">
<input type="text" name="message" size="55">
<input type="submit"name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the php

```
<?php
$host="myhost";
$user="myusername";
$database="mydatabase";
$table="mytable";
$connect=mysql_connect("$host","$user","mypassword");
if($connect){
echo "connected<BR/><hr/>";
$connect1=mysql_select_db("$database");
if($connect1){

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable(time,msg) VALUES('1','$message')");
echo "$message<BR/><hr/>";
}
}else{
echo "problem";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form is submitted using POST method then you can access dates using `$_POST`

Change `$message` to `$_POST['message']`

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable(time,msg) VALUES('1','{$_POST['message']}')");
echo "{$_POST['message']}<BR/><hr/>";
```

**Warning**
Note: Use `mysqli` or `PDO`. Using mysql functions are not recommended and it will deprecated soon.

Also you should add validation before inserting the data to database to avoid SQL injection or hacking. You code is not safe, it's open to attack.

Comment: it gave me an error unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: @jao  OP should take care of it. I put a warning message in my answer.

Comment: Try: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable(time,msg) VALUES('1','{$_POST['message']}')");`

Comment: @Muthu Kumaran not a problem and once again thank you for the help!